# HealthChecks UI Take Entries From Database

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-6.0, health-check

I am using https://github.com/Xabaril/AspNetCore.Diagnostics.HealthChecks and registering in ConfigureServices,

```
        services.AddHealthChecksUI(setupSettings: setup =>
        {

            setup.AddHealthCheckEndpoint("Test", "https://myDoman/healthz");
            setup.AddHealthCheckEndpoint("Test DB", "https://myDoman/healthz-db");
        }).AddInMemoryStorage();
```

It is working. But if I do,

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IDbService dbService, HealthChecksDb healthChecksDb)
{
        // Get NameFromDB using dbService service
        // Get UrlFromDB using dbService service
         ..........................................
         ..........................................
            healthChecksDb.Configurations.Add(new HealthCheckConfiguration
            {
                Name = NameFromDB,
                Uri = UrlFromDB,
            });
            healthChecksDb.SaveChanges(); 
}
```

It will show in the UI with error,

`Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: <. Path '', line 0, position 0.`

How can I add entries from DB?

Comment: How is the second snippet related to the first? What is throwing that error? `Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: <.` is typically shown when an API call gets back an HTML error page.

Comment: Its not throwing, its showing this error on UI of https://github.com/Xabaril/AspNetCore.Diagnostics.HealthChecks

Comment: That's already mentioned in the question. It's unclear what the code is doing or what error you're talking about. And I do use Xabaril and healthchecks over multiple services too. Do you get that in *your* application's UI? In the Healtcheck UI? Is that an error page, in which case there's an exception stack as well? Or just a popup? Have you tried to see the actual HTTP call in your browser's F12 Network tab?

Comment: `How can I add entries from DB?` the code doesn't do anything with any entries, it's adding a configuration and is probably missing some information. Why use such code instead of `setup.AddHealthCheckEndpoint("Test DB", "https://myDoman/healthz-db");` ? Given that Xabaril is open source, did you check what `AddHealthCheckEndpoint` is doing?

Comment: The [AddHealthCheckEndpoint](https://github.com/Xabaril/AspNetCore.Diagnostics.HealthChecks/blob/c1678488b36c8531544be8eda1e7b0daaea16426/src/HealthChecks.UI/Configuration/Settings.cs#L22) adds a Name/URL pair to an in-memory list. Nothing is saved to any database. The UI will use that URL to read the `healthz` response of the remote service, it won't try to read anything from any database. There may not be a database at all, if the user hasn't configured one. This has nothing to do with the `HealthCheckConfiguration` used to add specific health checks.

Comment: Here is the link https://github.com/Xabaril/AspNetCore.Diagnostics.HealthChecks/blob/f6d54c32dd9a25900ca043c257dbb34d43c3201c/src/HealthChecks.UI/Core/HostedService/HealthCheckReportCollector.cs#L47

Comment: The error coming in the UI `Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: <. Path '', line 0, position 0.
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ParseValue().......................
   at HealthChecks.UI.Core.HostedService.HealthCheckReportCollector.GetHealthReport(HealthCheckConfiguration configuration)`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I found the issue in the logs,:facepalm. The URL was wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking into source I checked logs, https://github.com/Xabaril/AspNetCore.Diagnostics.HealthChecks/blob/f6d54c32dd9a25900ca043c257dbb34d43c3201c/src/HealthChecks.UI/Core/HostedService/HealthCheckReportCollector.cs#L107

I found the URL was wrong in my case.